# Mac - Install from USB - Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, usb-drive, disk

I'm following the official instructions for [burning an Ubuntu image on a USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) from a macbook pro.

**Step 8** when trying

```
$ sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

I'm getting (after having typed my root password)

> dd: /dev/rdisk1: Permission denied

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the drive /dev/rdisk1 mounted? I have no experience of OS X, but in linux you often have to unmount a device before you can do some specific things.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same thing happen to me. There was a write-protect switch on the flash drive I was using. Once I switched it to enable writing onto the disk, it worked.